# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when calling a method as a source of an image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created this Angular 7 application where I'm trying to get the source of an image as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="showAllRec" class="pt-3">
<div *ngFor="let recommendation of allRecommendations">
  <div class="row pt-2">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img [src]="generateProfilePictures()">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
generateProfilePictures() {
  const profiles = [
  '../assets/profiles/dark-blue.png',
  '../assets/profiles/dark-grey.png',
  '../assets/profiles/light-blue.png',
  '../assets/profiles/light-green.png',
  '../assets/profiles/light-grey.png',
  '../assets/profiles/light-red.png',
  '../assets/profiles/medium-blue.png',
  '../assets/profiles/medium-brown.png',
  '../assets/profiles/medium-orange.png',
  '../assets/profiles/medium-purple.png',
  '../assets/profiles/medium-red.png',
  '../assets/profiles/medium-yellow.png',
  ];
  return profiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * profiles.length)];
```

}

The following results in an error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Any idea's why this is happening?

Comment: I have also tried using src={{ generateProfilePictures() }} but the error remains

Comment: You're constantly recalculating the random index. Also, you're constantly recreating the `profiles` array (more of a performance issue).

Comment: @FrankModica you are right about recreating the profile array everytime, I'll fix that but what's wrong with recalculating the index everytime? I do want a random path

Comment: Angular will call your `generateProfilePictures` function once for each element in `allRecommendations`, each time it does change detection. So you're constantly telling Angular a new random index - it doesn't know what number to use. Calculate that index up front and store it somewhere (or attach it to a property on `recommendation`).

Comment: @FrankModica I still don't see why that would be an issue? Sorry I'm fairly new to Angular. The solution you proposed seems to work fine though

Comment: In dev mode, Angular runs change detection twice to make sure the model hasn't changed after the first change. (Basically to ensure you have one-way data flow.). You may not get this error in a prod build, although I assume you'd still see your index changing every time you do something on the page (not sure that's desirable).

Answer (score 3):

This Error occurs, because in `development` Angular will run Change detection twice to make sure while the first CD run was being done, components which are already checked by CD should not change values while CD run is in Progress.

In your case the method `generateProfilePictures()` acts as a getter for `src` property and every get called by CD gets a different value.

RT now i am on a mobile device, so it's hard for me to prepare a stackblitz be demo.

But you can delay this calculation either by catching the index you are generating randomly, or wrapping the function content in a `settimeout`/observable (still have to try, can't be sure on a cellphone )

Answer (score 3):

Use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` into your component.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush  //<====Add this property
})
```

Here is working stackblitz: [ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Solved](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjicfj)